# Choosing the type of Index Variables

Tags: c++

We use Integer type represent index variables most of the time. But in some situations, we're forced to choose

```
std::vector<int> vec;
....

for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
....
```

This will cause the compiler to raise the warning that mixed use of signed/unsigned variables. if I make the index variable as `for( size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )`, (or an `unsigned int` )it will sort out the issues.

When it come more specific to use windows types, most of the Windows APIs are dealing with DWORD (which typedef-ed as unsigned long).

So when I use similar iteration, will again cause the same warning. Now if I rewrite it as

```
DWORD dwCount;
....

for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i)
....
```

I find this a bit weird. It might be the problem withe perceptions.

I agree that we are supposed to use the same type of index variable to avoid the range problems can happen with the index variables. For e.g if we're using

```
_int64 i64Count; // 
....

for(_int64 i = 0; i < i64Count; ++i)
....
```

But in the case of DWORD, or unsigned integers, are there any problems in rewriting it as

```
for(int i = 0; (size_t)i < vec.size(); ++i)
```

How most of the people are working with similar issues?

Comment: Why would you use a signed integer to represent index? That's like using vector of integers to store a string.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Because it makes the boundary conditions easier to test. For example on a count down to zero, a less-than test before executing the loop body cannot work with an unsigned value. Similarly a count up to the maximum doesn't work. Of course in that case a signed integer won't work either (because it can't represent such a large value).

Comment: "This will cause the compiler to raise the warning that mixed use of signed/unsigned variables."  That's only one of the _two_ problems you'll have to contend with.  In many cases `std::size_t` is a higher rank than int (or even long).  If the vector's size ever exceeds `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, you'll regret having used int.

Answer (score 11):

vector has a typedef that tells you the correct type to use :-

```
for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < thing.size(); ++i)
{
}
```

It's almost always defined to be size_t though but you can't rely on that

Comment: Not really an improvement in readability, IMHO.

Comment: No, but as it's the only way to tell what is the correct type to use for an index into the vector, that doesn't really matter...

Comment: Ouch, that's ugly! I'm finding more and more enjoyment in C++ by the day, for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: These days in c++11 just use auto

Comment: @JohnB You mean like `auto i = 0`? That doesn't help at all, `i` become an `int`.

Comment: Readability can be improved, with `using index_t = std::vector<int>::size_type;`.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<int> vec;

for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
```

Use an iterator for this, not a `for` loop.

For the others, as long as the variable type is of the same size, `static_cast` should work just fine (i.e. `DWORD` to `int16_t`)

Comment: `for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)` is a pain to write.  Having `for (auto i = vec.begin();...` is a whole lot more readable.  Of course, `foreach` is also in C++11.

Answer (score 4):

The case you described is one of the things I dislike in C++, too. But I have learned to live with that, either by using

`for( size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )`

or

`for( int i = 0; i < (int)vec.size(); i++ )`

(of course, the latter only when there is no risk of getting some int overflow).

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's warning you about comparison between signed and unsigned is because the signed value will likely be converted to unsigned, which might not be what you expect.

In your example (comparing `int` to `size_t`), `int` will be implicitly converted to `size_t` (unless `int` somehow has a larger range than `size_t`).  Thus, if the `int` is negative, it will likely be greater than the value you're comparing it to due to wraparound.  This won't be a problem if your index is never negative, but you'll still get that warning.

Instead, use an unsigned type (such as `unsigned int`, `size_t`, or, as [John B recommends](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104591/choosing-the-type-of-index-variables/104642#104642), `std::vector<int>::size_type`) for your index variable:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
```

Be careful when counting down, though:

```
for(unsigned int i = vec.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) // don't do this!
```

The above will not work because `i >= 0` is always true when `i` is unsigned.  Instead, use the "[arrow operator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71211/do-you-use-i-0-for-backward-loops/71282#71282)" for loops that count down:

```
for (unsigned int i = vec.size(); i-- > 0; )
    vec[i] = ...;
```

As other answers point out, you normally want to use an iterator to traverse a `vector`.  Here's the C++11 syntax:

```
for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
```

Comment: This still runs the risk that an `unsigned int` isn't large enough to hold the size.

Answer (score 2):

A new option for C++11, you can do things like the following

`for(decltype(vec.size()) i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {...}`

and

`for(decltype(dWord) i = 0; i < dWord; ++i) {...}`

While it repeats a little more than the basic for-loop would, it's not nearly as long-winded as pre-'11 ways of specifying values, and using this pattern consistently will work for most, if not all, possible terms you'd want to compare against, which makes it great for code refactoring. It even works for simple cases like this:

`int x = 3; int final = 32; for(decltype(final) i = x; i < final; ++i)`

Furthermore, while you should use `auto` whenever you're setting `i` to some intelligent value (like `vec.begin()`), `decltype` works when you're setting to a constant like zero, where auto would just resolve that to `int` because 0 is a simple integer literal.

To be honest, I'd like to see a compiler mechanism for extending the `auto` type-determination for loop incrementers to look at the value being compared against.

Answer (score 1):

I use a cast to int, as in `for (int i = 0; i < (int)v.size(); ++i)`. Yes, it's ugly. I blame it on the stupid design of the standard library where they decided to use unsigned integers to represent sizes. (In order to.. what? extend the range by one bit?)

Comment: In what situation would a collection size of negative anything be meaningful? Using unsigned integers for various collection sizes seems like the *sensible* choice, to me. Last I checked, taking the length of a string rarely returned a negative result either...

Comment: In what situation would it be meaningful for simple test such as `if(v.size()-1 > 0) { ... }` to return true for an empty container? The problem is that sizes are also often used in arithmetic, esp. with index-based containers, which is asking for trouble given that they're unsigned. Basically, using unsigned types for anything else than 1) bitwise manipulations, or 2) modular arithmetic is calling for trouble.

Comment: good point. While I don't really see the point of your particular example (I would probably just write `if(v.size() > 1) { ... }` since that makes the intent more clear, and as an added bonus the issue of signed/unsigned becomes void), I do see how in some specific cases signedness might be useful. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Michael: I agree it was contrived example. Still, I often write algorithms with nested loops: for(i=0;i<v.size()-1;++i) for(j=i+1;j<v.size();++j) .. if v is empty, the outer loop executes (size_t)-1 times. So I either have to check v.empty() before the loop or cast v.size() to a signed type, both of which I personally think are ugly workarounds. I choose a cast as it's fewer LOC, no if()s => fewer possibilites for mistake. (Also, in 2nd complement, conversion oveflow returns a negative number, so the loop doesn't execute at all.)

Comment: Extending the range by 1 bit was (and continues to be) very useful in 16-bit systems.